# Model java class as joined result in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, rdbms, one-to-one

Consider the following data. This is a fictional online store system. `Surcharge` store the surcharge configuration base on different goods category (food or clothing) and payment means (cash or credit card). `Packaging` store the available packaging option base on the goods category and payment means. If you paid the food by cash, sorry no premium packaging for you.

- underscore denote primary key.

[image]

[image]

`Surcharge` and `Packaging` is a one-to-many relationship. My situation is, I do not want to have 4 instance of `Surcharge` object and each has a `List<Packaging>`. I want to have 7 object and each hold a copy of `category`, `paymentMeans`, `surcharge`, `option`. Just like as they joined and the result would be 7 rows. How can I model my java class to achieve this? Thank you.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SURCHARGE")
public class Surcharge implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SurchargeId surchargeId;

    @Column(name = "SURCHARGE")
    private int surcharge;

    // how to map this attribute with packaging table as a single instance?
    private Packaging packaging;
}

@Embeddable
public class SurchargeId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_MEANS")
    private String paymentMeans;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PACKAGING")
public class Packaging implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PackagingId packagingId;
}


@Embeddable
public class PackagingId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_MEANS")
    private String paymentMeans;

    @Column(name = "OPTION")
    private String option;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Surcharge`, there will always be a list of `Packaging`. What you can do is to have one Surcharge object in `Packaging`. The code will be like below;

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_MEANS", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Surcharge surcharge;
```

If you don't want that, you can also create a DTO and populate it accordingly using JPQL.